# How to test useEffect hook only run once with mocha, enzyme and chai in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, mocha.js

**code**

```
const xyz = () => {

    const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getInitialData();
    }, []);

    async function getInitialData() {
        let response = api

        setInitialData(response.data);
    }

    return (
 
            <div>
               initialData.map(()=>{
               <li></li>
})
            </div>
    );
};

export default xyz;

**Test Case:**
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon'
import xyz from './../components/xyz';

describe.only('<xyz/>', function() {
 
    it('Expect the useEffect called only once', function() {
        sinon.spy(xyz.prototype, 'useEffect')

        const wrapper = mount(<xyz/>);
     
        expect(xyz.prototype.useEffect.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
        
    });


});

**Error:**

TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property useEffect as function
```

I have found that, in class based react component, there are some test cases to test lifecycle (componentdidMount), but I could not found anything to test useEffect with mocha and enzyme, when I tried, I am facing this error.

Comment: Why do you think `useEffect` exists on the `xyz.prototype`?